# how to check if string contains arabic character dart flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to check whether string contain arabic text or not. both string is in arabic language.

I have tried using contains method but its not working, don't know why this is happening.

```
_ayahList.forEach((item) {
  if (item.arabic.trim().contains(searchTxt.trim())) {
    _searchAyahList.add(item);
  }
});
```

but its not working.

EDIT

search text
الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا وَصَدُّوا عَن سَبِيلِ ال

Arabic text
الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا وَصَدُّوا عَن سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ أَضَلَّ أَعْمَالَهُمْ

SEARCH TEXT 2:
الرَّحِيمِ محمد

ARABIC TEXT 2 :
بِسْمِ اللَِّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ محمد

Comment: Did you test search without Arabic diacritic ?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It helps to [normalize](http://ibbtek.altervista.org/java/arabicnormalizer.html) the strings first, to remove diacritics.

```
void main() {
  String t2 = 'بِسْمِ اللَِّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ محمد';
  String s2 = 'الرَّحِيمِ محمد';

  print(t2);
  String nt2 = normalise(t2);
  print(nt2);
  print(t2.codeUnits);
  print(nt2.codeUnits);

  print(s2);
  String ns2 = normalise(s2);
  print(ns2);
  print(s2.codeUnits);
  print(ns2.codeUnits);

  print(nt2.contains(ns2)); // prints "true"
}

String normalise(String input) => input
    .replaceAll('\u0610', '') //ARABIC SIGN SALLALLAHOU ALAYHE WA SALLAM
    .replaceAll('\u0611', '') //ARABIC SIGN ALAYHE ASSALLAM
    .replaceAll('\u0612', '') //ARABIC SIGN RAHMATULLAH ALAYHE
    .replaceAll('\u0613', '') //ARABIC SIGN RADI ALLAHOU ANHU
    .replaceAll('\u0614', '') //ARABIC SIGN TAKHALLUS

    //Remove koranic anotation
    .replaceAll('\u0615', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH TAH
    .replaceAll(
        '\u0616', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH LIGATURE ALEF WITH LAM WITH YEH
    .replaceAll('\u0617', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH ZAIN
    .replaceAll('\u0618', '') //ARABIC SMALL FATHA
    .replaceAll('\u0619', '') //ARABIC SMALL DAMMA
    .replaceAll('\u061A', '') //ARABIC SMALL KASRA
    .replaceAll('\u06D6',
        '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH LIGATURE SAD WITH LAM WITH ALEF MAKSURA
    .replaceAll('\u06D7',
        '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH LIGATURE QAF WITH LAM WITH ALEF MAKSURA
    .replaceAll('\u06D8', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH MEEM INITIAL FORM
    .replaceAll('\u06D9', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH LAM ALEF
    .replaceAll('\u06DA', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH JEEM
    .replaceAll('\u06DB', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH THREE DOTS
    .replaceAll('\u06DC', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH SEEN
    .replaceAll('\u06DD', '') //ARABIC END OF AYAH
    .replaceAll('\u06DE', '') //ARABIC START OF RUB EL HIZB
    .replaceAll('\u06DF', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH ROUNDED ZERO
    .replaceAll('\u06E0', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH UPRIGHT RECTANGULAR ZERO
    .replaceAll('\u06E1', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH DOTLESS HEAD OF KHAH
    .replaceAll('\u06E2', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH MEEM ISOLATED FORM
    .replaceAll('\u06E3', '') //ARABIC SMALL LOW SEEN
    .replaceAll('\u06E4', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH MADDA
    .replaceAll('\u06E5', '') //ARABIC SMALL WAW
    .replaceAll('\u06E6', '') //ARABIC SMALL YEH
    .replaceAll('\u06E7', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH YEH
    .replaceAll('\u06E8', '') //ARABIC SMALL HIGH NOON
    .replaceAll('\u06E9', '') //ARABIC PLACE OF SAJDAH
    .replaceAll('\u06EA', '') //ARABIC EMPTY CENTRE LOW STOP
    .replaceAll('\u06EB', '') //ARABIC EMPTY CENTRE HIGH STOP
    .replaceAll('\u06EC', '') //ARABIC ROUNDED HIGH STOP WITH FILLED CENTRE
    .replaceAll('\u06ED', '') //ARABIC SMALL LOW MEEM

    //Remove tatweel
    .replaceAll('\u0640', '')

    //Remove tashkeel
    .replaceAll('\u064B', '') //ARABIC FATHATAN
    .replaceAll('\u064C', '') //ARABIC DAMMATAN
    .replaceAll('\u064D', '') //ARABIC KASRATAN
    .replaceAll('\u064E', '') //ARABIC FATHA
    .replaceAll('\u064F', '') //ARABIC DAMMA
    .replaceAll('\u0650', '') //ARABIC KASRA
    .replaceAll('\u0651', '') //ARABIC SHADDA
    .replaceAll('\u0652', '') //ARABIC SUKUN
    .replaceAll('\u0653', '') //ARABIC MADDAH ABOVE
    .replaceAll('\u0654', '') //ARABIC HAMZA ABOVE
    .replaceAll('\u0655', '') //ARABIC HAMZA BELOW
    .replaceAll('\u0656', '') //ARABIC SUBSCRIPT ALEF
    .replaceAll('\u0657', '') //ARABIC INVERTED DAMMA
    .replaceAll('\u0658', '') //ARABIC MARK NOON GHUNNA
    .replaceAll('\u0659', '') //ARABIC ZWARAKAY
    .replaceAll('\u065A', '') //ARABIC VOWEL SIGN SMALL V ABOVE
    .replaceAll('\u065B', '') //ARABIC VOWEL SIGN INVERTED SMALL V ABOVE
    .replaceAll('\u065C', '') //ARABIC VOWEL SIGN DOT BELOW
    .replaceAll('\u065D', '') //ARABIC REVERSED DAMMA
    .replaceAll('\u065E', '') //ARABIC FATHA WITH TWO DOTS
    .replaceAll('\u065F', '') //ARABIC WAVY HAMZA BELOW
    .replaceAll('\u0670', '') //ARABIC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALEF

    //Replace Waw Hamza Above by Waw
    .replaceAll('\u0624', '\u0648')

    //Replace Ta Marbuta by Ha
    .replaceAll('\u0629', '\u0647')

    //Replace Ya
    // and Ya Hamza Above by Alif Maksura
    .replaceAll('\u064A', '\u0649')
    .replaceAll('\u0626', '\u0649')

    // Replace Alifs with Hamza Above/Below
    // and with Madda Above by Alif
    .replaceAll('\u0622', '\u0627')
    .replaceAll('\u0623', '\u0627')
    .replaceAll('\u0625', '\u0627');
```